# How to capture messages for microsoft edge browser client area in spy++?

Tags: winapi, hook, microsoft-edge, spy++

I am running a spy++ 64-bit.
When i try to log messages for the edge browser's client area, i get nothing apart from WM_SETCURSOR.
However on the non-client region, i do receive all the messages.
Looks like edge hooks these messages with a thread specific hook and is not passing it further.
Any solutions to this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Edge does not compose page views from Windows Controls so there wont be messages there ...

Comment: i have hooks installed in my application and i want to know when someone does a mouse wheel on the edge client area. I do get a low level mouse hook callback but i can't use it for some reasons.

Comment: You can't on any recent version of Edge because it's running in a virtualized instance. Basically a container to prevent not only exactly this but to prevent malware from getting out as well.